# Scrambling in Languages like Latin

Tags: grammar, latin, word-order

Consider a clause in Latin that has n words. Latin frequently uses scrambling, so there are n! possible ways to arrange that clause given a free word order. However, Latin writers use only a small subset of those n! clauses. What criterion did they use to determine that subset?

Comment: Don't know how free that order really is... the few Latin I learned, I remember genitives were always placed adjacent to the words they possessed, preferably right before them. Word order departed from usual SOV for poetry, but then when using a subordinate phrase words could be scrambled only within the limits of the inner phrase. I'd say both restrictions would limit that n! by one or even 2 orders of magnitude...

Comment: Latin was written voluminously for almost two millennia,  mostly in Europe until recently. That means there were millions of writers, most of whom were not native speakers of Latin, all of whom had learned to write it by reading different books. Naturally, there were thousands of dialects over the centuries, even (perhaps especially) when it was still a spoken language and diverging into the Romance languages. Consequently there is simply no single rule, nor single **set** of rules, that everybody followed all the time. One did what one felt was correct, but one was often simply weird.

Comment: An example of how some of the n! permutations of words would yield incoherent sentences or completely invert the intended meaning: "lucretiae filius panem mangiat". If I say "filius lucretiae panem mangiat" it's still Lucretia's son. If I place "eats" right at the beginning or before the bread, still same meaning. However "Lucretiae mangiat panem filius" is non-sensical, whereas "Lucretiae panem filius mangiat" means Lucretia's bread's eaten by the son, something completely different from original sentence.

Comment: Another example, using subordinate phrases: "Hominus videt feminam et femina videt hominum". "Hominus feminam videt" or "feminam hominus videt" still mean "man sees female", likewise the 3 last words can be permutated. 1st subordinate phrase, word "and" and 2nd subordinate phrase can interchange places to some extent. But "Hominus femina videt feminam hominum videt" is simply non-sensical :)

Comment: There would be situations where certain orders are constrained for one reason or another. There always are. But they'd be different for every writer, according to their ideas and habits and purposes, so you can't generalize from them.

Comment: @JoePineda *mangiat* isn't Latin: the Latin for *eat* is *edere* or *comedere*. And *Lucretiae comest panem filius* certainly isn't nonsensical, though it isn't clear whether the son or the bread belongs to Lucretia.

Comment: @jlawler It's certainly possible to generalize, at least for Classical Latin prose; poetry is more of a free-for-all, while post-Classical Latin gets less and less free and starts to look more like modern western European languages. But word order in Classical Latin (and Greek) actually does obey certain pragmatic principles pretty well, and across authors; see the book I link to below.

Comment: Medieval Latin was stress-timed, like English. Classical Latin was syllable-timed, like Spanish. Poetry in a syllable-timed language doesn't sound like poetry to speakers of a stress-timed language, and v.v. Plus, since word order is pretty free in highly inflected languages, there's no way to tell how people talked, or myothomized, or sang, except for how somebody literate might have recorded them. Though literate people had better things to write than ordinary vulgar latin. So we really will never be able to say what actual Latin scrambling was like, since it's a spoken language rule.

Comment: @TKR my mistake, thanks - must've been thinking of Italian. I considered that phrase as non-sensical for it's not clear who does what to whom, though probably an ancient comedian would've appreciated such ambiguity :)

Comment: "Hominus" is not Latin either.

Comment: @jlawler I'm not sure what you mean by calling Latin scrambling a "spoken language rule"; there's plenty of pragmatically determined word-order variation in written Latin. I take the OP to be asking about this, and there are definitely useful generalizations to be made about it.

Comment: "Lucretiae filius panem comest". "Homo feminam videt et femina hominem videt". Just for the sake of leaving it right this time.

Answer (score 5):

There's not one criterion, but many, which are usually to do with discourse pragmatics and information structure: phenomena like topicalization, focalization, existential and presentative constructions, etc., can cause departures from Latin's usual SOV order. [This recent book](https://benjamins.com/catalog/slcs.117) (Spevak's *Constituent Order in Classical Latin Prose*) gives a lot of details.